# How do I get intern.js 2.1 to work with the new functionalSuites command line argument to intern-runner?

Tags: intern

if I do project>node node_modules\intern\bin\intern-runner config=my/config functionalSuites=mySuite it just hangs. If I omit functionalSuites, it works perfecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a bug in how Intern 2.1.0 handled the `functionalSuites` property. Intern has always assumed `functionalSuites` is an array. Specifying only a single instance of `functionalSuites` on the command line resulted in a string value (rather than an array) for `functionalSuites` in Intern, which would break the test runner.

The problem is fixed in [Intern 2.1.1](https://github.com/theintern/intern/releases/tag/2.1.1).

Comment: Csnover, I pulled it the day it was released and it works as if by magic. Thank you. This provides an easy way for a developer to focus on their test without meddling in the config.